# Akka streams, conditional divertLeft

Tags: scala, akka, akka-stream

I have a `divertLeft` function, based on the code here: https://bszwej.medium.com/akka-streams-error-handling-7ff9cc01bc12, which will divert Lefts to the specified sink, and pass Rights onward to the downstream consumer.

```
def divertLeft(to: Graph[SinkShape[(L, CO)], Mat]): FlowWithContext[I, CI, R, CO, Mat] = {
  flow.via {
    Flow[(Either[L, R], CO)]
      .divertTo(
        Flow[(Either[L, R], CO)]
          .collect { case (Left(element), c) => (element, c) }
          .to(to),
        _._1.isLeft
      )
      .collect { case (Right(element), c) => (element, c) }
  }
}
```

The actual processing upstream, returns `Left(new Exception(...))` in some circumstances, and `Left(new Error(...))` in others, and I'd like to handle these differently.

This is rather unlovable, but I'd hoped it might work...

```
def divertLeftIgnoreError(to: Graph[SinkShape[(L, CO)], Mat]): FlowWithContext[I, CI, R, CO, Mat] = {
  /* As above, but if the Left value is an Error, then ignore it instead of diverting to the given destination */
  flow.via {
    Flow[(Either[L, R], CO)]
      .divertTo(
        Flow[(Either[L, R], CO)]
          .collect { case (Left(element), c) if element.isInstanceOf[Error] =>  (element, c) }
          .to(Sink.ignore),
        _._1.isLeft
      )
      .divertTo(
        Flow[(Either[L, R], CO)]
          .collect { case (Left(element), c) if !element.isInstanceOf[Error] => (element, c) }
          .to(to),
        _._1.isLeft
      )
      .collect { case (Right(element), c) => (element, c) }
  }
}
```

... it doesn't. All the Lefts seem to be ignored, possibly because the `.collect` doesn't do what I think it does, and so the messages just fall off the end of the function without being handled. Can you even compose `divertTo` in that way?

I'd also considered writing a predicate (to pass to `divertTo`) for "`_._1.isLeft` and also the contents of that Left is an Exception", but I can't figure out the syntax for that.

Is trying to handle different kinds of Left just fundamentally ill-conceived? If so, what pattern should I be using to handle this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your issue is in the predicate function of `divertTo` as you thought. Any element that match the predicate will be diverted.

In your case, first `divertTo` diverts all `Left`. Then the sink collects only the errors and send them to ignore sink. The other `Left`s are filtered out by `collect`.

What you want is indeed a predicate more precise, like the one you wrote in the `case` of `collect`:

```scala
item => item._1 match {
  case Left(e) if e.isInstanceOf[Error] => true
  case _ => false
}
```

*(This is only an example of how to write it, there are actually other ways to write it like more inline `_._1.left.exists(_.isInstanceOf[Error])`, pick the one you prefer).*

Do the same for each predicate and it should work as expected.

Note that if you're going to ignore the `Left(Error(..)`, you could filter them our first and keep a single `divertTo`.

Comment: Thanks! Annoyingly, I wrote a predicate which I would have argued was the same as `_._1.left.exists(_.isInstanceOf[Error])` yesterday and it didn't compile... must have had a typo :( But yes, you're of course right that I can just literally ignore the things I want to ignore, and collect the rest.